# bash leaning on TR to format anwsers

Tags: bash, tr

I have a really bad habit of abusing tr. 
I need to find another way, a different style. 
all I want to so is print the list horizontally instead of vertically - so I can cut and past it into an email. Check out the use of the TR command. Just terrible.

```
$ cat /tmp/wig
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'monohajoxx' where user_name = 'monohajo'
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'wuemxx' where user_name = 'wuem'
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'taraziemxx' where user_name = 'taraziem'
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'mullankexx' where user_name = 'mullanke'
update PTMM_ARCHIVE.FASTTRACK_USER set user_name = 'fernanjaxx' where user_name = 'fernanja'
$ awk '{print $NF}' /tmp/wig | tr -d "'" | tr "\n" ", \s" ; echo  "\n"
monohajo,wuem,taraziem,mullanke,fernanja,\n
```

Comment: I don't see any questions here. If you're just looking for feedback, consider [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you  - code review  - I will check that out.  - you must agree that I am abusing the tr command. I mean there has to be a better way to get the list printed out that way by using a tool besides tr.

Comment: I honestly don't see anything wrong with it. That's a perfectly fine one-liner.

Comment: Did you really want that last comma after `fernanja`?  Typical comma-separated-value formats don't include that.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using awk

Here is one way to do it entirely with awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/'\''/,"",$NF); printf "%s%s",(NR>1?",":""),$NF} END{print "\\n"}' wig
monohajo,wuem,taraziem,mullanke,fernanja\n
```

The `gsub` command removes the single-quotes from the last field.  The `printf` command prints the last field preceded by a comma if this isn't the first line.  The final `print` statement finishes the line.

And, here is another:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",(NR>1?",":""),substr($NF,2,length($NF)-2)} END{print "\\n"}' wig
monohajo,wuem,taraziem,mullanke,fernanja\n
```

This uses a similar `printf` statement but uses `substr` to remove the first and last characters of the last field.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -nE "s/.*'([^']*)'/\1/"'; H; 1h; ${x; s/\n/,/g; s/$/\\n/; p}' wig
monohajo,wuem,taraziem,mullanke,fernanja\n
```

How it works:

- `-n` tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `-E` tells sed to use extended regular expressions so that we don't have to type as many backslashes.
- `s/.*'([^']*)'/\1/`

  This removes everything from the line except for the last field single-quoted string (with the quotes are removed).
- `H; 1h;`

  `H` adds a newline to the hold space followed by a copy of the current pattern space (which now contains the last field, minus the quotes).

  If this is the first line, however, the `h` command overwrites the hold space with just the current value of the pattern space (no newline).
- `${x; s/\n/,/g; s/$/\\n/; p}`

  On the last line, denoted by `$`, this does the following:

  ```
  - `x` exchanges the hold and pattern spaces.

  - `s/\n/,/g` converts all those newlines to commas.

  - `s/$/\\n/` puts a `\n` at the end.

  - `p` causes this pattern space to be printed.
  ```